# NSDatePicker to NSDate

Tags: macos, swift, nsdateformatter, eventkit

I am trying to make the date which is packed from the date picker become an NSDate, so I can create an event.

```
@IBOutlet var pckStartDate: NSDatePicker!
@IBOutlet var pckEndDate: NSDatePicker!


var dateFmt1 = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFmt1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    var _startDate:NSDate = dateFmt1(pckStartDate)
```

I obviously can't use the dateFromString() method because pckEndDate is not a string. How can I get this work? Does pckEndDate need to be converted to a String and then NSDate?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `dateValue` property:

```
let startDate: NSDate = pckStartDate.dateValue
let startDateString: String = dateFmt1.stringFromDate(startDate)
```